# data.table - Extract all the text features

Tags: r, data.table

As part of a function, I am trying to isolate all features that are either `character` or `factor`. My data set is a `data.table`.

```
text_features <- c(names(data_set[sapply(data_set, is.character)]), names(data_set[sapply(data_set, is.factor)]))
```

When I run the function I am getting an exception message that says :

> Error in `[.data.table`(data_set, sapply(data_set, is.character)) : 
>     i evaluates to a logical vector length 87 but there are 12992 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.

I understand this error is thrown by a recent version of `data.table` - How should I change my code to work the same way in order to avoid this error?

Note:

```
packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.10.4.3’
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because you have commas in the wrong place when you are subsetting your inner data.tables. You want a subset of the columns, not rows:

```
data_set[sapply(data_set, is.character)] # subsetting rows
data_set[,sapply(data_set, is.character), with = FALSE] # subsetting columns
```

All that said, I think a much cleaner solution would be:

```
text_cols <- names(data_set)[sapply(data_set, class) %in% c("character","factor")]
data_set[, ..text_cols] # subset data
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  In fact, I just noticed my function was previously configured to work with `read.csv` so that's why I mixed up the commas.  I think I need to review the full function to work for `data.table` - thanks for your support.